# SAS is the number lower than the highest number in the column so far

Tags: sas

I am using sas and I have a column in my table that consists of various numbers. I want to go down the column and select the number if it is smaller than the highest number so far. I posted a picture of an example of what I am looking for. I also have a column with the year, that I didn't post in the picture if that matters. I am guessing I will need some sort of loop.[n is the original column and output is what I would like my loop to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BfPx.png)

example:

### n - current column

```
    28
    22
    30
    40
    39
    55
    110
    89
    98
    160
    155
    157
    250
```

### output - desired output

```
    22
    39
    89
    98
    155
    157
```

I attempted this in proc sql because I am new to sas and know much more about sql. As I was attempting proc sql I realized I am not going to be able to do in proc sql.

Here is what I tried in proc sql.
I can post more things I have tried as I attempt more loops. As of now my loops are too far off.

```
proc sql;
  select a.*
  from homework a
  full join homework b on a.make = b.make
    and a.model = b.model
  where a.[Initial Model Year] < b.[Initial Model Year]
    and a.MPH < b.MPH;
quit;
```

Comment: Hi; welcome to the site.  Please include code that you've written to attempt to solve this problem, as well as the desired input/output in _text_ form (not image).  For more information, please read [ask] and the [help].  Thanks!

Comment: The data in your question is confusing. Why is 39 in the output? It’s not smaller than 22. From your description, I would expect the desired output to be one record with n=22. From your SQL, it looks like MODEL and YEAR are important to your logic. Can you add those variables to your sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why always use SQL?** SAS has a lot of facilities that are often more suited for the job dan SQL. Junior in SAS tend to use the only thing they know from school: SQL, and neglect all the rest.

By definition, **SQL is not suited for this job!** SQL does not even guarantee the order of rows is prevailed, let alone that you can use the order of the input rows in your logic. *(Yes, there are SQL dialects that can do this, but not standard SQL)*

**Use a `data` step.** That reads in your data row by row, in the order they occur.

**Avoid writing loops explicitely** whenever you can. The data step implicitely loops over it's input.

By default, the `data` step writes one row for each row read. You can remove a row from the output with a `delete` statement. You can also write explicit `output` statements. Then only the rows for which you do execute `output` wil be in the output. *(`output` is also used if you want more than one row in the output per row in the input.)*

However, by default, row by row means if forgets the previous row and all that is related to it. So you need to **explicitly `retain` some information**.

Attention, by default SAS keeps all intermediate results of calculations. If you don't want that, you need either an **explicit `keep` statement**, or a `drop`.

Example sollution:

```
data MY_SELECTION;
    set MY_INPUT;
    retain largest 0; * largest is initialized to 0 for the first row only *;
    if largest < number then largest = number;
    else if number < largest then output;
    drop largest;
run;
```

Final remark: By default, SQL writes a report and the `data` step creates a new data set. If you want SQL to behave as the `data` step, preceed your query with `create table MY_SELECTION as`. If you want the `data` step to behave as SQL, insert `proc print;` before the `run;`